# Непонятные сообщения при остановке сервера Tomcat

Tags: java, mysql, sql, tomcat, warning

Не могу понять с чем связаны следующие `warning`. Заранее буду благодарен!

```
 java.base@9.0.4/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.base@9.0.4/java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:70)
 java.base@9.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
 java.base@9.0.4/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
 java.base@9.0.4/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы запускаете tomcat, затем открываете приложение, потом останавливаете tomcat. Поскольку вы не закрыли ваши соединения с базой данных то это может привести к утечке памяти. Tomcat выпоняет проверку перед закрытием и автоматически очищает память. Поэтому вам приходят такие сообщения в виде   передупреждений.

Comment: То есть технически. Он делает закрытие и очистку памяти за меня?

Comment: не за тебя, а за себя.

Comment: Спасибо большое роман!)

Comment: Роман а вы не могли бы подсказать как от этого избавится? Что надо закрывать или очищать чтобы он мне этого не выкидывал?

Comment: Это специфичный вопрос, и на него невозможно ответить не рассматривая конкретную конфигурацию в используемом приложении. Для начала нужно грамотно писать приложение, т.е. чтобы в нем не было утечки памяти. Возможно утечка возникает от деплоя, т.е. когда две инстанции одного приложения загружаются одним класслоадером. Точно сказать не могу ввиду того что отсутствует пример воспроизведящий ошибку.

Comment: разобрался откуда шла утечка памяти. Я забыл переделать часть методов. В них не закрывался коннект к базе, от сюда и вылетали данные сообщения. После того сделал как должно было быть, переставло валится

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался я в тем была причина. Почему-то мой проект не хочет подхватывать подключенную библиотеку Mysql. Строчкой Class.forName("com.jdbc.mysql.Driver"), я заставлял его загружать данную библиотеку. Технически получалось что томкат загружал 2 раза одну и туже библиотеку. Во всяком случае я так понял. 1 раз из своих либ, сторой раз по принуждению.